# Java to Lotus Notes connection issue

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am trying to access the data from Lotus Notes database into an external Java program, but no luck.

On my laptop, I have configured IBM Domino 9.0.1 server, where I have created a demo database. My target is, to access the data from this database through external Java code. I have also installed Netbeans and Eclipse on the same laptop where Domino server is configured. Now, I am trying to access the demo lotus notes database in my java program (netbeans/eclipse) using the classes provided in Notes.jar package, but unable to open database.

To accomplish the task, I have followed below steps:

- Added the path 'C:\Program Files\IBM\Domino' to 'Path' system variable, and rebooted the laptop.
- In Netbeans (also tried in Eclipse), created Java class (console application), added Notes.jar file (IBM/Domino/JVM/lib/ext/Notes.jar) in the classpath (in netbeans, added Notes.jar in Resources section. In Eclipse, copied Notes.jar in lib folder).
- Added the following code in the class:
  (assume lotus.domino.* is already imported in the code)

  ```
      public static void main(String [] args)
      {
          try{
              NotesThread.sInitThread();
              //Case1
              Session session = NotesFactory.createSession()//Connect the server with server ID. Throws error 'Database has not been opened yet';
              //Also tried following options. Note that I have assigned full access/manager rights to anonymous user on the demo database
              //Case2
              //Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null);//Same result as first one [NotesFactory.createSession()]
              //Case3
              //Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null,"Romil Handoo/dev","My_Domino_Internet_Password");//Connect the server as Romil Handoo/dev login. Throws error- Invalid User Id/Password. I am giving correct ID/password
              //Case4
              //Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null,"","");//Access with anonymous user. Throws error 'Database has not been opened yet'**
              Database dbDemo = session.getDatabase(session.getServer(), "demo/DemoDB.nsf");
              //session.getServer() is returning my server name, which is Development/home. 
              //Also tried these, but same result each time: 
              //session.getDatabase("localhost:9595","demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //session.getDatabase("localhost","demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //session.getDatabase("127.0.0.1:9595","demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //session.getDatabase("127.0.0.1","demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //session.getDatabase("","demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //session.getDatabase((String)null,"demo/DemoDB.nsf")
              //Following line throws exception 'Database has not been opened yet'
              View vwDemo = dbDemo.getView("vwDemo");
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              System.out.println(ex.toString());
              //For case 1, case 2, and case 4, error message is 'Database has not been opened yet'
              //For case 3, error message is 'Invalid login id/password'

          }
          finally
          {
              NotesThread.stermThread();
          }
      }
  ```

Please someone guide me how I may connect to domino database through external java code? For all these steps, I have referred the page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS_JAVA.html

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the ACL of the DemoDB.nsf.  If I had to make a wild guess, I'd say that the group Local Domain servers is in the ACL and it is marked as a "Server Group", but your code is making a client connection so that's why cases 1, 2, and 4 fail. If it's not that, it's probably some other access issue.

Case 3 fails because you are supplying your internet password instead of the password for your actual user ID file. (Using the internet password only works with NCSO.jar and IIOP access, not with Notes.jar and NRPC access.)

Comment: Thanks @Richard for the observation. Actually in my environment, the notes and internet passwords are exactly same, so the code should not throw incorrect id/password error.

Comment: Richard, also requesting if you can assist me fixing the issue for case 1,2 and 4. I have checked the database ACL and found server group entry 'LocanDomainServers' having 'Manager' access, and 'OtherDomainServers' having 'No Access'.

Comment: Case 3 still doesn't work even if passwords are the same, because you are using user _name_ and password, not user id file and password. NRPC connections via Notes.jar require a user id and password.

Comment: In the ACL, change the 'User Type' dropdown for LocalDomainServers from 'Server Group' to 'Unspecified'.  Or just add the servername to the ACL and make that one 'Unspecified'. If that doesn't help, there are dozens of things that you might have to check. The first thing I'd do if I were consulting for you would be to check the value of session.username to confirm the assumtion in your comment that you are connecting with the server ID file.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try this. As I am printing 'Effective user name', here, showing server name (MyServerName/dev) in case 1 and case 2. For case 4, it is showing 'Anonymous', and case 3 is not working for me.